# RecyclerView/db not updated after closing activity

Tags: android

In one activity, I'm updating my db. I check to make sure the db is updated and finish() that activity. But when I'm on the previous activity, my db isn't updated and as a result my recyclerview is also not updated. Any ideas why?

Also, database call is in my onResume.

Oh one more key detail, it ends up updating, if I leave the activity and come back to it.

Comment: Wait... Let's say you are in Activity 1 where you have RecyclerView then starts Activity 2 in which your Database is updated. When you finish Activity 2 you want your RecyclerView in Activity 1 to be updated right?

Comment: The first one. When I finish Activity 2, I want Activity 1 to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()` in **Activity 1**, where you have your `RecyclerView`. But that is not the good approach. Everytime you will minimalize your activity and make it active again `onReceive()` will always be called even if your database is not updated.

All you have to do is to use `startActivityForResult()` from **Activity 1** like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, DB_UPDATE_REQUEST);
```

where `DB_UPDATE_REQUEST` is declared in **Activity 1** like this f.e.:

```
public static final int DB_UPDATE_REQUEST = 1;
```

In **Activity 2** after you update your database create `Intent`, set it's result to `RESULT_OK` if database was updated succesfully or to `RESULT_CANCELED` if database update was cancelled or interrupted like this:

```
if (your_db_update_status) {
    setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK);
} else {
    setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED);
}
finish();
```

In **Activity 1** retrieve information sent by **Activity 2** like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DB_UPDATE_REQUEST) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK: {
                Log.i("Activity 1", "Back from Activity 2. DB succesfully updated.");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            }
            case RESULT_CANCELED: {
                Log.i("Activity 1", "Back from Activity 2. Error in updateing DB.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think this is necessary if the db is what's having an issue updating? Because it was working before.. not sure what I changed... the db gets updated when I refresh the page... but the first time, it doesn't